# How to output the video path that is playing in MediaElement.js?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mediaelement.js

Is there a way to output or capture which video is playing in MediaElement.js. In particular, the actual format when in Internet Explorer.

I know in Chrome/Firefox you can right click the playing video and copy the video path which will give an indication of which video is playing, including the extension.

In Internet Explorer, which is using the Flash fallback, there is no such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the `mediaelement.js` options `enablePluginDebug: true`

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
   alwaysShowControls:true,
   startVolume: 1,
   enablePluginDebug: true
});
```